# what is the limit to infinity of $a^x/x$

Tags: limits

I need help with proving that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x} = \infty$$

I understand the logic but cannot seem to fit the epsilon-delta definition to it.

thanks

Comment: note that you should require $a > 1$ for this to work

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $n$ is integer and $a>1$ you have

$$a^n =(1+(a-1))^n > \frac{n(n-1)}{2} (a-1)^2$$

Use this, and the fact that there exists an integer $x-1 <n \leq x$ to conclude that for $x$ real you have

$$a^x > \frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{2} (a-1)^2$$

Comment: thanks, but why is (1+(a−1))n>n(n−1)2(a−1)2?

Comment: @user148005 $$(1+(a-1))^n =1+\binom{n}{1} (a-1)+\binom{n}{2}(a-1)^2+.... > \binom{n}{2}(a-1)^2$$